# CSS Image Caching

Tags: css, image-caching

In terms of client-side image caching, is there a difference between the following:

```
**Option #1**
<div style="background:url('myimage.jpg');display:none;"></div>
```

and

```
**Option #2**
<div id="myimage"></div>

style.css
#myimage {
     background:url('myimage.jpg');
     display:none;
}
```

EDIT: I'm not sure if it matters but the above DIVs are first loaded on another page with style="display:none;"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Also note that some browsers won't cache graphics ih hidden elements (regrardless of whether you hide them directly or hide one of their parent elements).

Comment: Which browsers don't cache graphics in hidden elements?

Answer (score 4):

No. Client caching is controlled by headers returned from the server in the request for the image, not the css.

As an aside, if you're looking for image caching, I highly recommend using a CDN. [Amazon's CloudFront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) makes this easy and cheap.

Comment: Alison is asking about client-side caching which is different subject.

Comment: Client caching is controlled by the cache headers on the request. Yes, CDN != client caching, but it is also very useful in situations when you are worrying about caching because of perf.